# compare two lists by elements and return the third list elements difference

Tags: python, list

I am trying to achieve the following but not able to get exactly what i want.

```
l1 = ['a','b','c']
l1_values = [1,2,3]
l1_new = [a,c]
```

compare l1 and l1_new lists and return relative position elements of 
l1_values

results:

```
l1_values = [1,3]
```

These lists are very long so loop through them is must to find the difference and different elements can be anywhere in list

Comment: Are all elements in `l1` unique?

Comment: Did you tried anything? Is there any code that you have written?

Comment: In `l1_new`, are `a` and `c` variables, as written, or did you mean them to be the strings `'a'` and `'c'`, as in `l1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all elements in `l1` are unique, you can create a dictionary from `l1` and `l1_values` and then look up the values while looping through `l1_new`:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(l1, l1_values))

[my_dict[k] for k in l1_new]
# [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = ['a','b','c']
l1_values = [1,2,3]
l1_new = ['a','c']

l1_values = [i+1 for i,v in enumerate(l1) if v in l1_new]
print l1_values
```

Output:

```
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

One-line solution, assuming `l1_values` may be different from given sequence:

```
[l1_values[x] for x, val in enumerate(l1) if val in l1_new]
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use a Simple 'for':

```
list1 = {'a': [print, 1], 'b': [print, 2], 'c' : [print, 3]}
list2 = ['a', 'b']

for data in list2:
    if data in list1:
        list1[data][0](list1[data][1])
```

Output (1) :

```
1
2
```

Another Example:

```
list1 = {'hi': [print, 'hi :)'], 'How are you?': [print, 'iam fine.'],
         'what is your name?': [print, 'my name is emma.']}
list2 = ['hi', 'what is your name?']


for data in list2:
    if data in list1:
        list1[data][0](list1[data][1])
```

Output (2) :

```
hi :)
my name is emma.
```